# how to solve "Your android sdk is missing, out of date or corrupted" error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed windows 10 recently. After windows installation I tried to install android studio. It was installed successfully with no errors. But when I wanted to make a new project it showed me this error:  **" Your android sdk is missing, out of date or corrupted"**

*how can I solve this error???*

I have read these links but no one can solve my problem:

[Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689102/your-android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-corrupted)

[How to solve "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or corrupted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334216/how-to-solve-your-android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-corrupted)

[Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you)

[image]

in the above picture when I clicked on "Open SDK Manager" this windows was opened
[image]
when I click on "Edit" next windows was opened

[image]

I clicked next --> next and then the wizard showed me this:
[image]

I have also downloaded sdk separately but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in
[Android Studio Update Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583394/android-studio-update-fails)

The reason of this problem is internet connection failure and it can be solved by the following post:

I have checked the base IDE's FAQs and found an answer that helped me out: edit the file ending with `.vmoption` in `Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin` and add the following option:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

or if you prefer IPv6:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```

It works for me.